# How to update multiple fields at once in mysql

Tags: mysql

Hello i am building a school management system and i want to promote all the students with one click to the next class. I want whenever i press auto promote button then it updates database with next class for example

```
update students 
set class=2 
where class=1 and 
set class=3 
where class=2 and 
set class=4 
where class=3
```

.

Comment: Please provide an example of the SQL code you're trying. That would make it an easier question for folks to answer.

Comment: i provided the example but just i joined stack overflow now so dont know to add code here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it with a single command

```
update students 
set class = class +1 
where class in (1,2,3);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the classes are integer you could increase the value by press the button.

```
class = class + 1
```

Ignore the where clause to update all.
Otherwise you have to write a script (f.e. javascript) that loads grouped students (by current class), finds out what's the current class (so you know what's the next one) and writes the class to them.
Important is that the algorithm must starts with the highest class.